# Node and talking to child processes

Tags: node.js, vscode-extensions, child-process, kill

### Context

Writing a serial monitor to listen to an Arduino isn't hard. Starting it with command line params for port name and baudrate is straightforward, and thus it's not complicated to configure and launch the monitor from Node:

```
child_process.exec("./monitor COM6 115200");
```

This question concerns `exec`, `fork` and `spawn` which are similar but with subtleties I do not yet grasp. As well as launch with parameters, I need to

- Capture the output so I can display it in a window
- Kill the child process

  - to re-launch with different parameters
  - to flash the Arduino and then re-launch after it reboots

I used netcore to write a console app that takes two command line arguments, then connects and listens, echoing to its `stdout`. I chose netcore because it can run on all three platforms.

### Questions

Which should I use of `exec`, `fork` and `spawn`?

How do I kill the child process?

How do I capture the `stdout` of the child process?

Node documentation talks about a [kill method on a `subprocess` object](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_subprocess_kill_signal). The sample code on that page implies this object is returned by `spawn` but when I use spawn it seems to fail silently. That or it's working but I don't know what I'm doing, which is why I'm posing this question.

All of this Node code will be part of a VSCode extension, so if you also know about those I'd like to pipe stdout to a VSCode OutputChannel if that's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With spawn your are able to listen to stdout.

and then kill process with kill()

From official NodeJS docs:

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const ls = spawn('ls', ['-lh', '/usr']);

ls.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});

ls.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.error(`stderr: ${data}`);
});

ls.on('close', (code) => {
  console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
});

// some logic
ls.kill()
```

EDIT: a more specific example:

```
// server.js --------------
const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer(
    (function() {
        console.log('Initializing server');
        return (req, res) => {
            res.end('Hello World');
        };
    })()
);

server.listen(8080, () => console.log('Server is up on port ' + 8080));

// spawn.js --------------
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

const child = spawn('node', ['./server.js']);

child.stdout.on('data', data => console.log(data.toString()));

child.stderr.on('data', data => console.log('Error: ' + data));

child.on('close', code => console.log(`Process ended with code ${code}`));

child.on('error', err => console.log(err));

setTimeout(() => child.kill(), 2000);
```

Comment: This looks very good. I have other code to sort out before I can try this but I think you've given me what I need to move on with my project. Perhaps a little explanation of the conceptual and differences, in particular the differences of intended use, between exec, fork and spawn to answer the question of why there are three ways to launch a process.

Comment: @PeterWone Absolutely! From my understanding the differences are minimal as all of these spawn child processes, however they do so in different manners. 

Use case is probably OS dependend.
execFile is pretty handy in UNIX systems it doesn't spawn a shell by default (runs executable files without a shell). 
On windows its probably a better idea to use exec as .bat and .cmd files cannot be executed without a terminal.

Spawn and Fork are similar except that fork spawns new Node processes, and has an extra communication channel that allows messages to be send between parent and child.

Comment: @PeterWone Spawn and fork spawn processes based on the specified command and passes the argumens provided.